# Google Sheets API - How to authenticate without interaction with user and browser?

Tags: node.js, api, google-sheets, google-api, google-sheets-api

I have a nodejs API, and need to consume Google Sheets API V4 data to populate a database.

I've been looking at the documentation on how to do authentication, but all the way I found to authenticate, it is necessary to perform user interaction to get a refreshed token

I need a way to perform authentication without having to interact with the user and browser, can someone help me?

Documentation I'm following: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/

Thanks!

Comment: Use service account to access the Sheets API. As stated in the document - [How to use "Service account" authorization (rather than user based access refresh tokens)](https://github.com/asimlqt/php-google-spreadsheet-client/wiki/How-to-use-%22Service-account%22-authorization-(rather-than-user-based-access-refresh-tokens)), you can use Service Account authorization which doesn't require the user-authorization-redirect flow, nor the use of refresh tokens. Hope it helps.

Comment: @Mr.Rebot The link you sent helped me. Thanks. Sharing with the unique app email was the key I was missing.

Comment: [Here is the code I use for writing to a Google Spreadsheet from NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44448029/how-to-use-google-sheets-api-while-inside-a-google-cloud-function/51037780#51037780).