# How to use authenticate a user for google sheets api on a remote server using Node.js?

Tags: node.js, google-sheets, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-sheets-api

I am working with Google sheets and node.js and I am able to authorize a user locally and get auth data using cmd using this tutorial https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/nodejs but cant authorize it on a remote server like Heroku so I have found an example https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/sheets-api/#4  but can't really grasp how to implement it in this example https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/nodejs.

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your requirements and architecture, it may make sense to write to the spreadsheet using a *service account*. [Here is my code for doing that from NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44448029/how-to-use-google-sheets-api-while-inside-a-google-cloud-function/51037780#51037780).

Advantages of service accounts:

- You don't have to do the OAuth dance (less code, fewer steps for the user).
- Your code can write to the spreadsheet even when no user has granted OAuth access.

Disadvantage:

- It's hard to enforce different access for different users, as all writes happen with whatever access you have granted to the service account.