# Firebase functions googleapis auth JWT = TypeError: authClient.request is not a function

Tags: firebase, google-sheets, jwt, google-cloud-functions, google-apis-explorer

I want to fetch shared google spreadsheet in a firebase web based project. I have used firebase functions for this.First i am getting the token by using google.auth.JWT and then trying to read spread sheet.Partially i am following [How to use Google sheets API while inside a google cloud function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44448029/how-to-use-google-sheets-api-while-inside-a-google-cloud-function). The functions code is following

```
exports.getNotes =functions.https.onRequest( (req, res) => {
  var jwt = getJwt();
  var apiKey = getApiKey();
  var spreadsheetId = '<spreadsheet Id/>';
  var range = 'Notes!A1:E1';
  appendSheetRow(jwt, apiKey, spreadsheetId, range)
  .then((result) => {
        //console.log(result);
      res.status(200).send(result);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        //console.log('error');
      res.status(500).send({ err });
    });

});

function getJwt() {
    var credentials = require("./credentials.json");
    var client =  new google.auth.JWT(
        credentials.client_email, null, credentials.private_key,
        ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly']
    );
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        client.authorize((err, tokens) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                console.log(tokens);
                // google.options({
                //     auth: client
                // });
                resolve(tokens);
            }
        });
    });
}

function getApiKey() {
  var apiKeyFile = require("./api_key.json");
  return apiKeyFile.key;

}

function appendSheetRow(jwt, apiKey, spreadsheetId, range, row) {
  const sheets = google.sheets({version: 'v4'});
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        console.log(spreadsheetId, range, jwt, apiKey);
        sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
            spreadsheetId: spreadsheetId,
            range: range,
            auth: jwt,
            key: apiKey,
        },function(err, result){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
                return err;
            }else{
                console.log(result);
                resolve(result.data.values);
                //return result;
            }
        });


  });
}
```

The firebase log result of code is

```
2018-12-28T05:47:43.993155161Z D getNotes: Function execution started
2018-12-28T05:47:44.001Z I getNotes: hello
2018-12-28T05:47:44.087Z I getNotes: <spread sheetID/> Notes!A1:E1 Promise { 
 <pending> } <Key/>
2018-12-28T05:47:44.093Z I getNotes: TypeError: authClient.request is not a function
at /user_code/node_modules/googleapis/node_modules/googleapis-common/build/src/apirequest.js:225:31
at next (native)
at /user_code/node_modules/googleapis/node_modules/googleapis-common/build/src/apirequest.js:19:71
at __awaiter (/user_code/node_modules/googleapis/node_modules/googleapis-common/build/src/apirequest.js:15:12)
at createAPIRequestAsync (/user_code/node_modules/googleapis/node_modules/googleapis-common/build/src/apirequest.js:57:12)
at Object.createAPIRequest (/user_code/node_modules/googleapis/node_modules/googleapis-common/build/src/apirequest.js:49:9)
at Resource$Spreadsheets$Values.get (/user_code/node_modules/googleapis/build/src/apis/sheets/v4.js:566:37)
at Promise (/user_code/index.js:265:32)
at appendSheetRow (/user_code/index.js:263:10)
at exports.getNotes.functions.https.onRequest (/user_code/index.js:222:3)
2018-12-28T05:47:44.124Z I getNotes: { access_token: '<my token/>',
 token_type: 'Bearer',
 expiry_date: 1545979664000,
 id_token: undefined,
 refresh_token: 'jwt-placeholder' }
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a very silly mistake I made on my side, Issue is because of wrong resolve like below

```
resolve(tokens)
```

but correct resolve looks like below

```
resolve(client)
```

Correct code snippet

```
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    client.authorize((err, tokens) => {
        if (err) {
            reject(err);
        } else {
            // Notice here
            resolve(client);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue with `TypeError: authClient.request is not a function` and changing the resolve to the client fixed it for me.

```
googleClient.authorize(async (err, tokens) => {
  if (err) {
    return res.badRequest({ success: false, error: err });
  } else {

    // Search for the sheet
    // with auth (auth must be the auth client, not `tokens`)
    let gsapi = google.sheets({
      version: 'v4',
      auth: googleClient
    });

    gsapi.spreadsheets.values.get(criteria, (err, res) => { ... })
  }
}
```