# Can I populate the data from Firestore to Google Sheet whenever a new record is added using a Cloud Function?

Tags: google-sheets, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to build this app where I am planning to store my data in a Firestore database. My client needs the data in a Google Sheet.

Can I use Cloud Function to directly populate the records from Firestore to a Google Sheet and whenever a new record will be added to the Firestore, Google Sheet will be updated automatically?

Can anybody suggest any resource that can help on this topic?

Answer (score 6):

Yes,  you can use cloud function with Firestore trigger that is notified when your firestore document is changed, in the function you would call google API to update google sheets.

You can find an [example](https://github.com/adrianwit/serverless_e2e/tree/master/cloud_function#realtime-database) of end to end tested cloud function app with firestore triggers.

Answer (score 3):

While the other options provide ways to do it with code, you may want to also look into using a service like Zapier which takes about 30 seconds to set up and requires zero coding.

Setting Firebase updates to trigger to Google Sheets is supported out of the box and should do what you want really easily.

Check this link:

https://zapier.com/app-directory/firebase/integrations/google-sheets

[image]

Comment: Link is not valid

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to create a service account that can communicate between the Firestore database and the Google Cloud function. The Google Cloud Function can then update a Google Sheet using the Google Sheets API. As for resources to put you on the right track:

[How to read/write to a google sheet.](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values)

[Service account docs.](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts)

And lastly, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44448029/how-to-use-google-sheets-api-while-inside-a-google-cloud-function) similar case that should answer any other questions you have.