# How do I add my Cloud Firestore to Google Sheets?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, spreadsheet

I'm pretty new to app development, but managed to put something together using Flutter.

The app requires registered users to submit information they provide by selecting from a series of drop down lists.

I managed to set up a Cloud Firestore database from my Firebase account, but was wondering how I can move the collected information onto a Google Sheets spreadsheet?

From my account every time new information is provided, it overwrites the old information instead of keeping a record of each instance.

Can anyone help with both of these issues?

I am currently using the Spark plan.

Help would be much appreciated!

EDIT:

pubspec.yaml

`cloud_firestore: ^0.12.9+4`

database.dart

```
import 'package:epddiary/models/user.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class DatabaseService {

  final String uid;
  DatabaseService({ this.uid });

  // collection reference
  final CollectionReference diaryCollection = Firestore.instance.collection('diary');

  Future<void> updateUserData(String operativeName, String operativeNameHours, String plantName, String plantNameHours, String sectionofWork, String activityCode, String notifications, String uploadImage) async {
    return await diaryCollection.document(uid).setData({
      'Operative Name': operativeName,
      'Operative Name (hours spent on activity)': operativeNameHours,
      'Plant Name': plantName,
      'Plant Name (hours spent on activity)': plantNameHours,
      'Section of Work': sectionofWork,
      'Activity Code': activityCode,
      'Notifications': notifications,
      'Upload Image': uploadImage,
      // 'strength': strength,
    });
  }

  // entry list from snapshot
  List<Entry> _entryListFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    return snapshot.documents.map((doc){
      //print(doc.data);
      return Entry(
        operativeName: doc.data['Operative Name'] ?? '',
        operativeNameHours: doc.data['Operative Name (hours spent on activity)'] ?? '',
        plantName: doc.data['Plant Name'] ?? '',
        plantNameHours: doc.data['Plant Name (hours spent on activity)'] ?? '',
        sectionofWork: doc.data['Section of Work'] ?? '',
        activityCode: doc.data['Activity Code'] ?? '',
        notifications: doc.data['Notifications'] ?? '',
        uploadImage: doc.data['UploadImage'] ?? '',
        // strength: doc.data['strength'] ?? 0,
      );
    }).toList();
  }

  // user data from snapshots
  UserData _userDataFromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
    return UserData(
      uid: uid,
      operativeName: snapshot.data['Operative Name'],
      operativeNameHours: snapshot.data['Operative Name (hours spent on activity)'],
      plantName: snapshot.data['Plant Name'],
      plantNameHours: snapshot.data['Plant Name (hours spent on activity)'],
      sectionofWork: snapshot.data['Section of Work'],
      activityCode: snapshot.data['Activity Code'] ?? '',
      notifications: snapshot.data['Notifications'] ?? '',
      uploadImage: snapshot.data['Upload Image'] ?? '',
      // strength: snapshot.data['strength']
    );
  }

  // get entries stream
  Stream<List<Entry>> get entries {
    return diaryCollection.snapshots()
    .map(_entryListFromSnapshot);
  }

  // get user doc stream
  Stream<UserData> get userData {
    return diaryCollection.document(uid).snapshots()
      .map(_userDataFromSnapshot);
  }

  }
```

auth.dart

```
import 'package:epddiary/models/user.dart';
import 'package:epddiary/services/database.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

class AuthService {

  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  // create user obj based on firebase user
  User _userFromFirebaseUser(FirebaseUser user) {
    return user != null ? User(uid: user.uid) : null;
  }

  // auth change user stream
  Stream<User> get user {
    return _auth.onAuthStateChanged
      //.map((FirebaseUser user) => _userFromFirebaseUser(user));
      .map(_userFromFirebaseUser);
  }

  // sign in anon
  Future signInAnon() async {
    try {
      AuthResult result = await _auth.signInAnonymously();
      FirebaseUser user = result.user;
      return _userFromFirebaseUser(user);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }

  // sign in with email and password
  Future signInWithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      AuthResult result = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
      FirebaseUser user = result.user;
      return user;
    } catch (error) {
      print(error.toString());
      return null;
    } 
  }

  // register with email and password
  Future registerWithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      AuthResult result = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
      FirebaseUser user = result.user;
      // create a new document for the user with the uid
      await DatabaseService(uid: user.uid).updateUserData('','','','','','','','');
      return _userFromFirebaseUser(user);
    } catch (error) {
      print(error.toString());
      return null;
    } 
  }

  // sign out
  Future signOut() async {
    try {
      return await _auth.signOut();
    } catch (error) {
      print(error.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }

}
```

user.dart

```
class User {

  final String uid;

  User({ this.uid });

}

class UserData {

  final String uid;
  final String operativeName;
  final String operativeNameHours;
  final String plantName;
  final String plantNameHours;
  final String sectionofWork;
  final String activityCode;
  final String notifications;
  final String uploadImage;

  UserData({ this.uid, this.operativeName, this.operativeNameHours, this.plantName, this.plantNameHours, this.sectionofWork, this.activityCode, this.notifications, this.uploadImage });

  // Method to make GET parameters.
  String toParams() =>
      "?operativeName=$operativeName&operativeNameHours=$operativeNameHours&plantName=$plantName&plantNameHours=$plantNameHours?sectionofWork=$sectionofWork?activityCode=$activityCode?notifications=$notifications?uploadImage=$uploadImage";
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you're going to have to get started writing code to read from Firestore, figure out what the spreadsheet should look like given that data, and write to the spreadsheet, which are all very different things to tackle.

Comment: Is there a simple way to import what I've already created using the Cloud Firestore? I tried following a tutorial on the Firebase YouTube channel (can I provide a link here?), but I get an error.

Comment: Yes, you can provide the link here. Please have a look into the following similar post which will help you to solve your issue [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58020160/8791788) and this external tutorial to [sync your firebase with Google Sheets](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/sheets-to-firebase-33132e31935b)

Comment: And also please have a look into this [youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MdRLezi88fw) as well.

Comment: Regarding your second question, how are you loading data or adding new information to Firestore? Could you please share your code?

Comment: Looking through the links you provided, Zapier seems to do what I want, thanks Nibrass!

To add data I followed The Net Ninjas video tutorials on YouTube.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mtNA1neFNVo&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9j--TKIdkb3ISfRbJeJYQwC&index=16

How best can I include the code I use?

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, Please share the code , I mean, update your post, with the code when you are adding the data to Google Sheets, and could you please explain more about the error you are getting?

Comment: And also please share the code or explain how are you loading the data to firestore as you mentioned it is getting overwritting?

Comment: Thanks Nibrass, I've added my code into my original post - hopefully it helps.

I've since found the following App Script, which doesn't involve Firebase or Zapier.

https://medium.com/mindorks/storing-data-from-the-flutter-app-google-sheets-e4498e9cda5d

Does that to you seem like a good way to go i.e. do I need Firebase for what I intend to do (keep an automatically updated record of user input on an app that is stored in a Google spreadsheet).

Comment: I will have a look into you code, meanwhile , could you please point out where are you getting the error, or what error are you getting? Thanks for sharing the code.

Comment: Thanks Nibrass, I've changed the code and managed to get my data appearing on Google Sheets, though it is with its own issues.

I've only just managed this and want to have a look at the code myself, but if it comes to it I will post it hear, replacing the above code.

Please disregard the code that is currently there.