# How can I compare a Google spreadsheets data with a firestore data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, google-cloud-firestore, google-sheets-api

I have this specific code:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'
import { google } from 'googleapis'
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase-admin/app'
const serviceAccount = require('../sheets_updater_service_account.json')
const sheets = google.sheets('v4')
import { getFirestore  } from "firebase-admin/firestore"
initializeApp()
const firestore = getFirestore()


module.exports.readAndUpdateAdministrativeSheet = functions.https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {

    // =========================== AUTENTICAÇÃO FIREBASE ===================================
    const jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT({
        email: serviceAccount.client_email,
        key: serviceAccount.private_key,
        scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']
    })

    await jwtClient.authorize()


    // ================= CONEXÃO COM A PLANILHA CRIAÇÃO DE FILTROS =========================
    const { data } = await sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
        auth: jwtClient,
        spreadsheetId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
        range: `Listagem de pagamento!A2:X6`,
    })

    // ========= CRIAÇÃO DE BANCO DE DADOS DA COLEÇÃO LISTAGEM DE PAGAMENTO ================
    const generateDuplicities = data.values!.map(async row => {
        const [idade, nome, cpf, cpf_x, numeroRequerimento, arbitramentoHonorários,
            valorArbitrado, valorDeferido, valorComplementar, status, resultado, codigoBanco,
            banco, agencia, conta, dataDoRequerimento, dataRequerimento, dataStatus,
            comarca, vara, ato, assistidos, email, telefone] = row
        firestore.collection("Listagem de pagamento").doc(numeroRequerimento).set({
            idade, nome, cpf, cpf_x, numeroRequerimento, arbitramentoHonorários,
            valorArbitrado, valorDeferido, valorComplementar, status, resultado, codigoBanco,
            banco, agencia, conta, dataDoRequerimento, dataRequerimento, dataStatus, comarca, vara, ato,
            assistidos, email, telefone
        })
// =========================== DUPLICIDADE ADMINISTRATIVA ===================================        
        const duplicitiesWithAdministrativeCharges = new Array()
        const resultduplicitiesWithAdministrativeCharges = firestore.collection('Protocolos finalizados') //1lGPC1UuxVRplJCVfAXAPWeigjgx1ETyx1OpdtCCJoXo (Pagamentos finalizados)
            .where("autosPF", "==", arbitramentoHonorários) // autosPF => Planilha Pagamentos finalizados  /  arbitramentoHonorários => Planilha de Criaão de filtros
            .where("cpf_PF", "==", cpf) // cpf_PF => Planilha Pagamentos finalizados  /  cpf => Planilha de Criação de filtros
        const resDuplicitiesWithAdministrativeCharges = await resultduplicitiesWithAdministrativeCharges.get()
        if (resDuplicitiesWithAdministrativeCharges.size) {
            resDuplicitiesWithAdministrativeCharges.forEach(doc => {
                if (resDuplicitiesWithAdministrativeCharges.size == 1) {
                    functions.logger.log("Foi encontrada " + `${resDuplicitiesWithAdministrativeCharges.size} ` + "duplicidade administrativa referente a pessoa " + `${nome}.`)
                    functions.logger.log(doc.id) // NÃO MEXER
                    functions.logger.log(doc.data()) //NÃO MEXER
                    functions.logger.log('requerimento: ', doc.data().requerimento) // NÃO MEXER
                    functions.logger.log('mesPagamento: ', doc.data().mesPagamento) // NÃO MEXER
                    // Requerimento e mesPagamento devem vir da planilha de pagamentos finalizados
                    duplicitiesWithAdministrativeCharges.push(`${'arbitramentoHonorários'}: ${arbitramentoHonorários}`, `${'nome'}: ${nome}`, `${'requerimento'}: ${doc.data().requerimento}`, `${'mesPagamento'}: ${doc.data().mesPagamento}`)
                    functions.logger.log(duplicitiesWithAdministrativeCharges)//NÃO MEXER
                } else if (resDuplicitiesWithAdministrativeCharges.size > 1) {
                    functions.logger.log("Foram encontradas " + `${resDuplicitiesWithAdministrativeCharges.size} ` + "duplicidades administrativa referente a pessoa " + `${nome}.`)
                    functions.logger.log(doc.id)
                    functions.logger.log('requerimento: ', doc.data().requerimento) // NÃO MEXER
                    functions.logger.log('mesPagamento: ', doc.data().mesPagamento) // NÃO MEXER
                    // Requerimento e mesPagamento devem vir da planilha de pagamentos finalizados
                    duplicitiesWithAdministrativeCharges.push(`${'arbitramentoHonorários'}: ${arbitramentoHonorários}`, `${'nome'}: ${nome}`, `${'requerimento'}: ${doc.data().requerimento}`, `${'mesPagamento'}: ${doc.data().mesPagamento}`)
                    functions.logger.log(duplicitiesWithAdministrativeCharges)//NÃO MEXER
                }
            })
        }    
        else if (resDuplicitiesWithAdministrativeCharges.size <= 0){
            functions.logger.log('Não há duplicidades administrativas nesta lista')
            //console.log('Não há duplicidades administrativas nesta lista')
        }
})
    await Promise.all(generateDuplicities)
})
```

I want send the {duplicitiesWithAdministrativeCharges} functions.logger result´s to a google spread sheets.

The result´s need to be sended in this order to the spread sheet.

1. `arbitramentoHonorários` it will be in a specific column `Arbitramento de honorários` (column A(1))
2. `nome` it will be in a specific column `Nome do autor` (column B(1))
3. `doc.data().requerimento` will be in a specific column `Requerimento de pagamento` (column C(1))
4. `doc.data().mesPagamento` will be in a specific column `Listagem de pagamento` (column D(1))

Does anyone know how I can send the result data from my code to another Google spreadsheet?

Comment: I found a particular [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58018791/can-i-populate-the-data-from-firestore-to-google-sheet-whenever-a-new-record-is) that might help you on how to send the data from one side to another? I also found this excellent script that can be linked to a [Google Sheet](https://www.lido.app/post/quick-way-firestore-to-google-sheets)

Comment: @RicardoJoseVelasquezCruz thanks for your answer, but in this case I need something without send the data to google sheets to firestore. I want compare the "where's" without create a database "Listagem de pagamento".